# Oracle SQL and strtotime - updating record

Tags: php, sql, oracle, datepicker, strtotime

When I update a record, I am occasionally getting the year of 1969 being inserted into my field. The year updated from 2016 to 1969 ?? IS there a STRTOTIME issue with the date? I am not sure where the issue lies ...

1. I am selecting date from the table

   ```
    SELECT to_char(a.MOV_DATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') as MOV_DATE FROM SCHOOL.MOV a
   ```
2. I am inserting the date into a JQuery Datepicker input...

   ```
    <input type="text" name="movdat" id="datepicker" class="boxit" required readonly="readonly" style="cursor:pointer; background-color: #FFFFFF; width:140px;" value='<?php echo $objResult["MOV_DATE"]; ?>'>
   ```

datepicker:

```
     <script>
       $(function() {
         $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
           dateFormat:'dd-M-yy',
           maxDate: 0
         }).val();
        });
      </script>
```

So the format from Oracle is DD-Mon-YYYY and from the datepicker is dd-M-yy

dd ( 2 digit day )

M ( month - short )

yy ( 4 digit year )

so they look like they match.

3. PHP - store date from datepicker and extract year

   ```
   $f4 = $_POST['movdat']; // new date

   $f5 = date('Y', strtotime($f4)); // year
   ```
4. Update Record

   ```
     $sql = oci_parse($conn,"UPDATE SCHOOL.MOV SET MOV_DATE=:mdat,
                                                   YEAR=:ye
                                               WHERE id='265'");


     oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':mdat', $f4);
     oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':ye', $f5);

     $objExec = oci_execute($sql, OCI_DEFAULT);

     if ($objExec) {  
        oci_commit($conn);
     }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`to_date`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132) function to explicitly tell Oracle in which format to expect the input string and convert it to a `date` object for internal processing:

```
UPDATE SCHOOL.MOV SET
  MOV_DATE = to_date(:mdat, 'DD-Mon-YYYY'),
  YEAR = :ye
WHERE
  id = '265'
```

Comment: If the datepicker is in the format of 04-Sep-2017, should the to_date function be to_date(:mdat, 'DD-Mon-YY') or to_date(:mdat, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') ? And does it matter if its Mon or MON ??

Comment: Case is important when formatting for output (using `to_char`) as [Oracle will follow the same convention](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51077). But it doesn't seem to affect things with `to_date`. [You should always use 4 digit year format](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51076).